# MariaDB ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value for values before 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This is the short version of my table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `birthday` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

I can't insert time values before 1970-01-01 00:00:00.
I get this error: 
ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value: '1964-02-19 16:57:55' for column 'birthday.

How can I fix that?

This is my server version.

[image]

Comment: 'The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html Any particular reason for using timestamp instead of datetime (for example)?

Comment: Or for a birthday, just a `date` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Mysql Documentation, TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. 
To solve the problem, I changed the column from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME.